# How often does iOS Safari clear its cache?

Tags: ios, caching, safari

I use mobile Safari cache to store some data that I want to be persistent, so I would prefer that they would survive both Safari restarts and iOS restarts.

(Please don't suggest me to use cookies or Local Storage here - that's not what I am asking about.)

However I have read [some new](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74797/can-i-force-a-cache-refresh-in-safari-running-on-ios#comment159599_74812) and [some old](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/02/06/iphone-cacheability/) reports that Safari clears its cache on Safari restart. But my non-scientific tests on Safari 8.3 showed me that sometimes this cache can in fact not only survive application restart but even the iOS reboot (!).

So I am a bit confused at this point.

**Are the rules of iOS Safari cache clearing documented somewhere?**

**Does any of you know them and can explain them to me (and the world ;)?**

Comment: Apple's Safari Client-Side Storage and Offline Applications Programming Guide still suggests using Local Storage.
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

Hope someone find that I'm wrong but..

I searched a lot and I guess there are no resources about how the automatic cleaning policy works in Safari. And knowing Apple policy I guess that it's  simply because this information is not necessary both for users and developers.

If you want to ask to Safari to protect your cache, you can use the Manifest File as described there:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH4-SW1

Comment: Unfortunately for the Manifest File to work the whole site needs to be yours = you need to have control over <html> element, and in my case these are not my sites and I don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about ios safari, but in general the browser reserves some storage space for cached items. When that space fills up, it starts deleting the cache.
Another factor that may trigger the cache deletion may be when the operating system tries to clear the temporary files.

So, a short answer would be: you don't know. That depends from user to user of how often it is deleted.